# how to skip a module from rebuild

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a module in my project that contains native c code and that is updated once in a while. I would like to avoid to rebuild it at every compilation, to speed up build time, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem some time ago. I improved my build times by adding the following lines to gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache-problems=warn
```

Also I would suggest to go over the official
[docs](https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build#groovy) for further improvements.